# Monitor not connecting to desktop computer via HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, display, hdmi

I recently bought a new desktop computer, but I am having issues connecting my monitor to it. When I attempt to connect the monitor by connecting it to the graphics card via HDMI, I get a black screen (No video input), and the same happens if I attempt to connect the monitor to the motherboard via DVI. Connecting the monitor to the motherboard via VGA works just fine, however. I have already connected the monitor to other computers via HDMI and DVI with the same cords, and have no problems doing so.

The monitor in question is a Philips Brilliance 234CL. The graphics card is a Radeon RX 480, and the Motherboard is an ASUS H110M-A DDR4.

I hope someone is able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that your monitor, by default, uses an input other than HDMI and therefore you must switch it to HDMI every time?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Now I'm just embarrassed that it was so simple. Thanks.

Comment: No problem and I thought of this as my monitor has an HDMI, VGA and DVI output and by default my monitor is either VGA or DVI (can't remember) and had I not watched a YouTube video about my monitor I wouldn't have known that myself! :)